# How to change where Google Analytics for iOS stores its sqlite file?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, app-store, icloud

Google analytics stores a sqlite file in /Documents

App-store approval process may not like this, because of the iCloud backup ...

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: How big is the file likely to get? (I have an app on the store with a sqlite file in there 100MB big - we're rewriting it to be more user friendly but it's not stopping new versions being approved in the meantime)

Comment: @deanWombourne is this a question? or you've got an approval for an app with google analytics sqlite file in docs folder without setting the "do not backup" flag?

Comment: I meant I have an app approved with a sqlite file 90MB big in the documents folder. However, looks like @thomas' answer solves your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the [release note of version 1.4](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/ios.html#changeLog)

> Changed location of the database to from the Documents directory to the Library directory